# Referral Url Data not getting tracked in Google Analytics

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have url say pfsites-sites/homepage when user enter this url in the browser and press enter. User is directed to www.xyz.com. homepage

I want pfsites-sites/homepage as referral url to xyz.com.

I used HTTP referrer variable in GTM. But data is not getting tracked.

Can anybody help to track the referrer  url

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the visitor is getting redirected to xyz.com, after entering pfsites-sites/homepage.

The visit to pfsites is counted as a direct visit and the redirect (301 or 302) would normally pass the referrer to xyz.com. But after entering the URL directly into the browser there is no referrer at all.

You can use this website http://www.whatismyreferer.com/ to check your referrer, after the redirect and you should ensure that the redirect is passing the referrer information.

Please take note that the referrer information gets lost, after switching from https to http.

Hope that helps.